# How to use exist label to show correct answer

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm beginer. I saw another questions like mine, but I have different problem.

I have two questions:

1.I want use exist label to show correct answer.

In this app, after every answer, it only return image- wrong or correct answer. 
There is no question text and correct answer text, how in usual quiz.
It's looks like on picture. Last image shows what I expect after changes.:
http://i62.tinypic.com/65ahe0.jpg

I think about change:
-use existing label, first under question text (UIButton *Answer1) to show correct answer under picture wrong/correct answer.

-show question text over correct answer text. I think I need change -QuestionText.hidden from YES for NO.

2. I wrote 90 questions in quiz, so I use:
   arc4random() %89;  // 0-89

It's work in Simulator.

I read here,  arc4random () % working only to 51.
Will be a problem with it on device ?

Thank you for your help.

.m file:

```
#import "Game.h"
@interface Game ()
@end
@implementation Game
-(void)RightAnswer{
    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 1;
    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ScoreNumber];
    NextCategory.hidden = NO;
    Answer1.hidden = YES;
    Answer2.hidden = YES;
    Answer3.hidden = YES;
    Answer4.hidden = YES;
    QuestionText.hidden = YES;
    CategorySelected.hidden = YES;
    Result.hidden = NO;
    Result.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rightanswer.png"];
}
-(void)WrongAnswer{
    LivesNumber = LivesNumber - 1;
    Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", LivesNumber];
    NextCategory.hidden = NO;
    Answer1.hidden = YES;
    Answer2.hidden = YES;
    Answer3.hidden = YES;
    Answer4.hidden = YES;
    QuestionText.hidden = YES;
    CategorySelected.hidden = YES;
    Result.hidden = NO;
    Result.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wronganswer.png"];

    if (LivesNumber == 0) {

        Result.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gameover.png"];
        NextCategory.hidden = YES;
        Exit.hidden = NO;
        GameInProgress = NO;
    }
}
-(IBAction)Answer1:(id)sender{
    if (Answer1Correct == YES) {
        [self RightAnswer];
    }
    else{
        [self WrongAnswer];
    }
}
-(IBAction)Answer2:(id)sender{
    if (Answer2Correct == YES) {
        [self RightAnswer];
    }
    else{
        [self WrongAnswer];
    }
}
-(IBAction)Answer3:(id)sender{
    if (Answer3Correct == YES) {
        [self RightAnswer];
    }
    else{
        [self WrongAnswer];
    }
}
-(IBAction)Answer4:(id)sender{
    if (Answer4Correct == YES) {
        [self RightAnswer];
    }
    else{
        [self WrongAnswer];
    }
}

-(void)Category1{

    switch (QuestionSelected) {
        case 0:
            QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What Team Won The 2012/2013 English Football Premier League?"];
            [Answer1 setTitle:@"Manchester United" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer2 setTitle:@"Manchester City" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer3 setTitle:@"Liverpool" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer4 setTitle:@"Chelsea" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            Answer1Correct = YES;
            break;
        case 1:
            QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Which City Hosted The 1992 Olympic Games?"];
            [Answer1 setTitle:@"Norwich" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer2 setTitle:@"Barcelona" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer3 setTitle:@"Tokyo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer4 setTitle:@"Lisbon" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            Answer2Correct = YES;
            break;
        case 2:
            QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By What Score Did England Win The Ashes In The Summer of 2013?"];
            [Answer1 setTitle:@"5-0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer2 setTitle:@"4-0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer3 setTitle:@"3-0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer4 setTitle:@"2-0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            Answer3Correct = YES;
            break;
        case 3:
            QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What Team Won The NBA Playoff Finals In 2013?"];
            [Answer1 setTitle:@"Golden State Warriors" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer2 setTitle:@"Memphis Grizzlies" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer3 setTitle:@"San Antonia Spurs" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [Answer4 setTitle:@"Miami Heat" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            Answer4Correct = YES;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (GameInProgress == NO) {
        LivesNumber = 3;
        ScoreNumber = 0;
        GameInProgress = YES;
    }
    Result.hidden = YES;
    Exit.hidden = YES;
    NextCategory.hidden = YES;

    Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", LivesNumber];
    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ScoreNumber];

    Answer1Correct = NO;
    Answer2Correct = NO;
    Answer3Correct = NO;
    Answer4Correct = NO;

    CategoryLoaded = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"CategorySaved"];
    QuestionSelected = arc4random() %4;

    switch (CategoryLoaded) {
        case 1:
            CategorySelected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sport"];
            [self Category1];
            break;
        case 2:
            CategorySelected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Films"];
            [self Category2];
            break;
        case 3:
            CategorySelected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Music"];
            [self Category3];
            break;
        case 4:
            CategorySelected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Games"];
            [self Category4];
            break;
        case 5:
            CategorySelected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Geography"];
            [self Category5];
            break;
        case 6:
            CategorySelected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"History"];
            [self Category6];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

.h file:

```
NSInteger CategoryLoaded; //This has been updated from int as used in the videos, as this is used for saving and loading data. There have been some issue on the later devices using an int for this and not NSInteger
int QuestionSelected;
BOOL Answer1Correct;
BOOL Answer2Correct;
BOOL Answer3Correct;
BOOL Answer4Correct;
int ScoreNumber;
int LivesNumber;
BOOL GameInProgress;


@interface Game : UIViewController
{

    IBOutlet UILabel *CategorySelected;
    IBOutlet UILabel *QuestionText;
    IBOutlet UIButton *Answer1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *Answer2;
    IBOutlet UIButton *Answer3;
    IBOutlet UIButton *Answer4;
    IBOutlet UIButton *NextCategory;
    IBOutlet UIButton *Exit;
    IBOutlet UILabel *Score;
    IBOutlet UILabel *Lives;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *Result;


}

-(IBAction)Answer1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Answer2:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Answer3:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Answer4:(id)sender;
-(void)Category1;
-(void)Category2;
-(void)Category3;
-(void)Category4;
-(void)Category5;
-(void)Category6;
-(void)RightAnswer;
-(void)WrongAnswer;


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

1- I can't understand it, can you elaborate more ?

2- No it will work fine to whatever range you specify, but note that if you need to generate random number between 0 to 89 (0 and 89 are included) you need to make it `arc4random() %90;`

Comment: Thanks you.     1. After every answer app shows image: 'wronganswer.png' or 'rightanswer.png'. What I want? After question from this code e.g. (first one): 'What Team Won The 2012/2013 English Football Premier League?' I will press 'Manchester United', so it will be show image 'rightanswer.png' and under it question text: 'What Team Won The 2012/2013 English Football Premier League?' under this in new or existing label, correct answer so 'Manchester United'. I added link (above) which shows what I need (last image whith text NEW- red rectangles).

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not clear enough for me, are you asking about whether you should add the correct answer with the question in the same label , or in a new one ?

Comment: Sorry for not clear answer.   Question text in the same label.
Correct answer in the same label (first under question text label- UIButton *Answer1 ), if that is possible.